# Yup - Typing a retrieved field schema from an Object schema

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yup

I've finally decided to upgrade from Yup `0.29` to `1.2` and faced some issues with it's types. I'm Looking for help to find a best solution for typing yup schemas.

In `0.29` quite universal type `Schema` used to fit everywhere, but now it doesn't.

### 1. <s>Yup Object Generic</s>.

<s>Here I Expect for compiler to complain, because Yup Object Schema doesn't satisfy my Generic type, how do I make this schema to be invalid because of MyType? Also to be more strict, it should complain when field is not optional, but `.required()` or `.nullable()` is not set.</s>

```js
interface MyType {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const mySchema = yup.object<MyType>({
  id: yup.number().required(),
  // name: yup.string().required(), <--- Here compiler used to raise an error in 0.29
}).required()
```

Edit: First issue is solved, found an explanation [here](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/1906)

### 2. Typing a retrieved field schema from an Object schema

Here I have components and functions, where I have an argument - a field schema (string/number/object, etc)

```js
interface MyType {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const mySchema = yup.object<MyType>({
  id: yup.number().required(),
  name: yup.string().required(),
}).required()

const idSchema = yup.reach(mySchema, "id");
const nameSchema = yup.reach(mySchema, "name");

function validateField(fieldSchema: Schema) {
  fieldSchema.validate("TEST")
}

validateField(idSchema) // <--- Here compiler complains, where in 0.29 it didn't
```

[image: field schema error]

I'm not quite sure about this `Reference | ISchema` type, cannot find Reference type in Yup exported interfaces.

Comment: I couldn't find a `Schema` type or class in `yup@0.29.0`. Are you sure you used that exact version?

Comment: I've used `yup: "^0.29.1"` and `@types/yup": "0.29.1"` to be precise. Now yup types are no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the external type definitions were necessary in `yup@0.29.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this PR](https://github.com/jquense/yup/pull/1758/commits/234f999873903434a40349410556a2bc1cac0f4f), which was made almost a year ago, returning a type of `Reference` and `ISchema` is supposed to make the types more ***intelligent***. You'll see that `reach` internally [makes use of](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/master/src/util/reach.ts#L76C48-L76C48) [`getIn`](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/master/src/util/reach.ts#L6), which goes through the schema to return either an `ISchema` or a `Reference`, this is better because when one defines a schema, they might have a `Reference` field using [`ref`](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/master/src/index.ts#L98) -

```ts
import { ref, object, string } from 'yup';

let schema = object({
  baz: ref('foo.bar'),
  foo: object({
    bar: string(),
  }),
  x: ref('$x'),
});

schema.cast({ foo: { bar: 'boom' } }, { context: { x: 5 } });
// => { baz: 'boom',  x: 5, foo: { bar: 'boom' } }
```

And the `ref` creates an object of type (you guessed it), [`Reference`](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/master/src/Reference.ts#L20). Note that the other types such as [`object`](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/master/src/object.ts#L99), [`number`](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/master/src/number.ts#L33) etc., all extends `Schema` (parsed recursively), but that's not the case for a reference created by `ref`, so, when you're trying to [`reach`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#reachschema-schema-path-string-value-object-context-object-schema) and you have a schema like the one showed above, you might get a `Reference` or `Schema`, and hence the added types are better.

#### How to get around for your use case?

You can make use of an assertion utility [`isSchema`](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/master/src/util/isSchema.ts#L3), provided by the library, like so -

```ts
import yup, { isSchema, ISchema, ref } from "yup";

type Reference<TValue = unknown> = ReturnType<(typeof ref<TValue>)>;

interface MyType {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

const mySchema = yup.object<MyType>({
    id: yup.number().required(),
    name: yup.string().required(),
}).required();

const idSchema = yup.reach(mySchema, "id");
const nameSchema = yup.reach(mySchema, "name");

function validateField<T>(field: ISchema<T> | Reference) {
    if (isSchema(field)) return field.validate("TEST");

    throw new Error("Can't validate a Reference without a schema");
    // Or add your own implementation for validating reference
    // you can modify signature of validateField for that
}

validateField(idSchema); // no error
validateField(nameSchema); // no error
```

Here's a [Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WPBZKN).

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed explanation. However I find it weird, it's quite difficult to achieve this, I blame poor yup documentation. Secondly, I would expect for Reference type to be exported. Unless reach shouldn't be used in the way I do. Anyways, it really helped me, I will accept the answer.

Comment: Ask the lib author to export Reference type by opening an issue.